# Host 2 webapps under the same domain in Azure

Tags: azure, dns, routes

Is there a way to configure same domain for multiple Azure webapps(same domain, not subdomain)?

I would like to have **http://myCustomDomain.com/WebApp** and **http://myCustomDomain.com/WebApi**
where the first one is the website and second one the API.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would not be possible with any DNS based solution, since each webapp deployment would have an IP and same domain can't resolve to both. The DNS server can't make any decisions based on the URL (domain resolution will take place once every 5-30 minutes or so and not per request)

I have seen in work with load balancers (via [IRules](https://www.udemy.com/f5-load-balancer-irule-fundamentals/)), but haven't seen anything similar supported for Azure Webapps. Subdomain is what people use in the absence of such fancy load balancers, but you have already ruled that out.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use virtual directories for that:

To create a new virtual application, go to the Configure tab of the Azure Web Site and go to the bottom of the page.  You will see a section called “virtual applications and directories”.  In here, we can create a completely separate application that runs in its own directory, with its own web.config and publishing profile.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/09/21/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website/

http://www.microsofttrends.com/2015/02/02/publishing-to-azure-web-sites-with-multiple-virtual-applications/

Comment: this means that i still have only one Azure WebApp(no scale, no individual deploy)? do you know if i can do this for multiple webapps?

Comment: sorry? you can scale a webapp, whats the problem?

Comment: if both services are in the same webapp, then they can't be scaled independently (4 instances for webapp, 10 for api etc)

Comment: no they can't be, since its just a virtual directory, but you know, no one forces you to use 1 webapp, just saying. @AVS